# Kio estas la signifo de "falsidas"?

Tags: word-meaning

Mi legis *Gerda malaperis* kaj mi trovis la vorton *falsidas*. Ĝi ŝajnas esti kunmeto de *fal-* kaj *sidas*, sed mi ne scias kion *fal-* signifas. Tiu ĉi vorto nek estis en mia vortlisto por ĉapitro naŭ nek en Vikivortaro, eĉ en la esperanta versio, kaj Google-Tradukilo diras *fake*, kiu ne havas sencon en la kunteksto de *La flegistino iras al Bob, kiu **falsidas** ĉe la koridora muro*.

I was reading *gerda malaperis* and I came across the word "falsidas". It seems to be a concatenation of "fal-" and "sidas", but I don't know what "fal-" means. This word was neither in my vocabulary for chapter nine, nor on Wiktionary, even in the Esperanto version, and google translate says "fake" which doesn't make any sense in the context, "La flegistino iras al Bob, kiu **falsidas** cxe la koridora muro.".

Mi pardonpetas por mia gramatiko kaj literumado, se mi faris erarojn.

Answer (score 10):

*Fali* means *to fall*. It is in Wiktionary [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fali). So I guess *falsidi* is meant to be self-evident from the combination of the two roots, ie, that he fell down into a sitting position. Perhaps a good English word for this could be *slump down*.

Answer (score 0):

Falsidi-- to plop down; to fall onto your rear end.  If we say "vi falsidis", you didn't just sit down,  you fell into a sitting position.

Answer (score 0):

*Fali* is indeed to fall (down).

*Sidi* is to sit (to be in a sitting position), while to sit down (to change oneself into a sitting position) is *sidiĝi* or *eksidi*.

While you normally sit on a chair or a bench, I think here falling indicates that you have fallen down, which depending on the context can mean that *vi falsidas* when you sit on your butt or on the floor.